# JSF Updating Composite Component (Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I have the following UI Primefaces snippet:

```
<pou:growl id="growl" 
               redisplay="false"
               showDetail="false" 
               sticky="false" />
```

When I try to update this item, for example like this:

```
<pou:commandButton value="Update" 
                   update=":growl"/>
```

Everything works fine.

When I move growl to a composite component however and try to call it (ie. like this):

```
<ez:growl/>
```

I get an error maessage that says:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":growl" referenced from "j_idt84:j_idt85:testForm:j_idt111".
```

My question is why are all these auto generated names being added and how can I control them so I can actually access the components to update?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because composite components inherently extend from [`UINamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) (like as `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, etc) and thus prepend the client ID of their children with own ID.

To achieve your particular functional requirement, first give your composite component a fixed ID:

```html
<ez:growl id="growl"/>
```

Then embed the `<p:growl>` in the composite component's implementation in a plain HTML container element like `<div>` or `<span>` with the composite component's client ID as element ID:

```html
<cc:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <p:growl />
    </span>
</cc:implementation>
```

Now you can just use `update=":growl"` the usual way.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I didn't understand exactly how to apply your answer : I have one <ui> component included inside of another xhtml, inside of a <p:tabView>. Can you please tell me how to addapt to my case ? Thanks !

Comment: @loan: Are you using a composite component or not? (as in, you're using `<cc:interface>` and `<cc:implementation>` where `cc` is from `http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite`).

Comment: No, I have a simple main.xhtml, containing <p:growl id="growl"/>, and one <p:tabView, which has inside more <p:tab>, and inside of one of the <p:tab> I do : <ui:include src="form.xhtml" />. This form is inside of a <ui:composition>. That's all. It worked until I added menu tab view part..

Comment: @loan: Then the answer don't apply to you at all. Continue searching or ask a new question. In the meanwhile, this general answer may apply if you're facing the error message mentioned in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762