# Updating composite overlayPanel

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, composite

Based on this [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690635/jsf-updating-composite-component-primefaces), I would like to update a `<p:overlayPanel>` from a datatable to a composite component

**View**

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:dataTable id="myTable" ...>
        <p:column headerText="1">
            <p:commandLink id="link" 
                           actionListener="#{bean.update}" 
                           update=":toto" value="Val" />
            <p:overlayPanel id="panel" for="link">
                <my:view id="toto">
            </p:overlayPanel>
         </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**Composite**

```
<composite:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <p:dataTable id="toto" ...>
        </p:dataTable>
    </span>
</composite:implementation>
```

However I always get an error message saying that `:toto` component id can not be reached.

So, how can I access the dataTable placed in the composite ?

**EDIT** : Actually I changed my mind concerning the utilisation of `p:overlayPanel` for a `p:datatable` because of the creation of dynamic ids. I replaced this by a `p:dialog` and it works great.